# SUMPRODUCT using an array as a condition

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm trying to create a function that sums the number of NO's in an array for multiple different names.
Basically the array looks like the image below and I want to sum all of the no's for the specified names. Breaking it into separate conditions is not an option because the list of names will be changing frequently.

**This is an example of what it looks like**

[image]

My formula so far is `=SUMPRODUCT(--(A1:A10=H2:H4),--(B1:E10="NO"))` but it won't let me use an array as a condition. I've tried using COUNTIF as well, but it doesn't work with arrays of different sizes like I have.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use MATCH and ISNUMBER:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(ISNUMBER(MATCH(A1:A10,H2:H4,0))*(B1:E10="NO"))
```

Comment: Not exactly sure how it works but it did! Thank you!

Comment: @JasperSommer - if it worked considering marking as answer. Or, if you like, choose the other answer, but the key to SO being a great site is for questioneer's to mark their questions as solved when they get a satisfactory answer. :)

Answer (score 3):

If you have O365 with the `FILTER` function, you could use:

```
=SUM(N(FILTER(B1:E10,COUNTIF($H$2:$H$4,$A$1:$A$10))="NO"))
```

If you don't have that function, you can use:

```
=SUM(N(IF(COUNTIF($H$2:$H$4,$A$1:$A$10),$B$1:$E$10,"")="NO"))
```

or

```
=SUMPRODUCT(N(IF(COUNTIF($H$2:$H$4,$A$1:$A$10),$B$1:$E$10,"")="NO"))
```

*Note the typo with regard to `Keith` vs `Kieth`.  If those are all spelled the same (`A4`,`A7`,`H3`) the total would be `7`.*

[image]

Comment: @JvdV That would have been the case had I typed the names the same :-).  But I've got a `Keith` and a `Kieth`, so only `Keith` is being counted.  If you change the name in `A4` to Keith, it'll --> 7